# expected a ")" in IAR IDE

Tags: c, msp430, iar

I got the error `Error[Pe018]: expected a ")"` at `CPU_state == cpuStateOff`.
When I change `cpuStateOff` to `0` it's OK. I don't know why.

In my `PERIPHERAL_APP.h`:

```
#ifndef __PERIPHERAL_APP_H
#define __PERIPHERAL_APP_H
// CPU state
#define CPU_STATE_OFF     0;
#define CPU_STATE_ON      1;
#endif
```

In my `main.c`:

```
#include "PERIPHERAL_APP.h"
void main( void )
{
    initMSP430();  
    _EINT();                              
    for (;;)
    {
        if (cpuState == CPU_STATE_OFF ) // The error is hear 
        {
            __bis_SR_register(LPM3_bits);
        }
        else
        {
            __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: `#define cpuStateOff     0;` remove the semi-colon

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please learn to indent your code. It doesn't matter for the compiler, but for humans readability is very important, and at least *some* indentation of code makes it much more easy to read (and therefore easier to maintain).

Comment: Also unrelated to your problem, but symbol names, even preprocessor names, beginning with double underscore, or beginning with a single underscore followed by an upper-case letter, are *reserved* for the "implementation" (compiler and standard library) in all scopes. You should not use such names for your own names.

Comment: Please edit your question and indent the code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you for your suggestions! I will fix it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preprocessor macros are not C statements, and therefore doesn't need a statement terminator like `;`.

What happens is that when the preprocessor replaces the macro `cpuStateOff` it uses the *whole* body of the macro, i.e. `0;` which results in code like

```
if (CPU_state == 0; ) // Code after macro replacement
```

Most compilers and environments have options to stop after preprocessing, if you use it you can see exactly what code the compiler "proper" will see.

Comment: i didn't know IDEs provide a way to see the pre-processed source. Good to know!